# Can't find element in Capybara even though it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am writing some Capybara tests, and am failing at what seemed to be quite straight forward search. I have HTML:

```
<div id="divId">

     <div class="unimportantClass">
     </div>

     <form id="formId">

        <div>
        </div>

        <h2>Irrelevant text</h2>
        <p>Equally irrelevant</p>

        <span class="remarkableSpan">
            <i class="whatever"> </i>
            Some text
            <input id="targetTag">
            </input>
        </span>

     </form>

</div>
```

I am trying to confirm existence of "targetTag"

Everything goes well in

```
expect(page).to have_css('div#divId form#formId span.remarkableSpan')
```

but with

```
expect(page).to have_css('div#divId form#formId span.remarkableSpan input')
```

or

```
expect(page).to have_css('div#divId form#formId span.remarkableSpan input#targetTag')
```

it fails to find it. Any ideas what is causing it?

Comment: is this a test running with javascript? are you sure this element is visible?

Comment: The answer to the both questions is yes.

Comment: i assume that the last answer is NO and that's why the test fails. make sure there is nothing hiding this element. did you try using xpath or one of the other selectors? did you inspect the `page.body`?

Comment: i tried have_xpath("//input[@id='targetTag']") but failed. As for now I was not able to find anything causing this object to be invisible...

Comment: @phoet's point makes sense. Try to mimic the same behavior in browser to see if they are visible. You can also type `$('targetTag')` in console to see what output.

Comment: you could try the debugging method explained in "Debugging capybara" in this post: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: I'll check it out. BTW $('targetTag') returns the object's info in the console. Manually I can do whatever I wish with this input. Just wondering if the fact that input't type is file can matter here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158868/capybara-can-not-find-element-by-id

Comment: this happened to me right just then. I couldn't "choose" radio button. It turns out the label for it had padding that covers the radio button itself, and it was impossible to click "the radio button", although you can click the overlaying label and seems like you are actually clicking radio button.