# Capybara can not find element by id

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

Capybara is not able to find a `<p>` tag by it's id in my cucumber test. I'm able to see the element when I `save_and_open_page`. But I can't locate it with `has_css?` or `find`:

```
pry(#<Object>)> page.html.scan(/notice_sent/).count
=> 1
pry(#<Object>)> page.html.scan(/id=\"notice_sent\"/).count
=> 1
pry(#<Object>)> page.find('#notice_sent')
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css "#notice_sent"
from /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.1.7/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:41:in 'block in find'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default Capybara doesn't find elements that are not visible on the page.  You can try

```
page.find('#notice_sent', visible: :all)
```

to see if that's the case.  If so, and you're testing an app, then you should perform whatever actions a user would perform that would make that element visible, and then check for its presence.

Comment: Yep - the id was on the page but wasn't visible until I added a click on a tab

Answer (score 1):

Though I am a newbie to Capybara, I think this might work for you !!

```
page.find('#notice_sent', :visible => false)
```

Also, add this code to your `env.rb` file.

```
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
```

Comment: Setting ignore_hidden_elements to false is a really bad idea 99% of the time, especially if you're using Capybara as a testing tool.  It will lead to incorrectly passing tests for a lot of UI issues.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is good in most cases, however, there are times that elements may dynamically present; and not just hidden.  When using `find` and the element is not present we get an error very similar to when it is present, but hidden. How do we handle that case?

[Capybara::Node::Finders#all](https://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara%2FNode%2FFinders:all) Also known as: `find_all`, has the same visibility option as `find`, but will not throw an error when there are no matches.

```
page.all('#notice_sent', visible: :all)
```

This is very similar to `where` vs `find` in ActiveRecord, and there are uses for both approaches.

if you want to return the matching element or `nil` instead of an Array / collection, then you can append `first` and get a result that closer matches the behavior of `find` without the error.

```
page.all('#notice_sent', visible: :all).first
```

Answer (score -2):

I think, it is time to update capybara for the very beginning.

And, I can not test it out now, but try `page.html.find('#notice_sent')`

Comment: page.html return a string so `find` is not a valid method

Comment: To use finders on a string you would need to create a Capybara::Node::Simple from it like `Capybara.string(page.html).find(...)` - while this is possible, it's really better just to figure out why Capybara isn't finding the element in the session - see my answer